# Karate Cucumber reports in Junit 4 without parallel execution

Tags: karate

I'm using Karate with Junit 4.

I have one suite:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({ ExampleRunner1.class, ExampleRunner2.class })
public class ExampleSuiteIT {}
```

and runners like this:

```
@RunWith(Karate.class)
@KarateOptions(tags = {"~@ignore"})
public class ExampleRunner1 {}
```

I want to generate a cucumber.json file to use some report tool like [Cluecumber](https://github.com/trivago/cluecumber-report-plugin)

Is it mandatory to use the parallel execution to generate Cucumber reports? I saw the implementation of [DemoTestParallel](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/DemoTestParallel.java) and there is a lot of code there. I'm trying to avoid code in my suite class and also I don't need parallel execution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it mandatory to use the parallel execution to generate Cucumber reports

Using the `Runner` class is mandatory to generate the Cucumber JSON files. If you don't want parallel execution, use a thread count of 1. Then it is up to you what you want to do with the JSON files.

Comment: It will be GREAT an annotation for parallel runner metadata (paths, tags, threads)

Comment: @italktothewind you are the only one who wants this. contribute code, it is open source

Comment: @italktothewind I don't :) you can always write an annotation yourself and use it for all your projects. and you can publish it via github and those who want will use it.

Comment: I have another little question, is there a way to count the tests properly with surefire/failsafe using parallel runner? Because now I have this in the logs: Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

Comment: @italktothewind looks correct to me. follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Before submitting the issue... If I have 20 features files that are run in a single test using parallel runner is ok to have "Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0" in the logs? Or the expected behaviour is "Tests run: 20, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0"?

Comment: @italktothewind it depends. make sure you follow the instructions EXACTLY as described in the link